# Como pegar texto do CkEDITOR com PLUGINS do MySQL

Tags: php, ckeditor

A minha dúvida é a seguinte, configurei o CKEditor com PLUGINS dentro de um textarea, onde tudo que eu digitar envia para o banco de dados que ao mesmo tempo alimenta outra página, funcionando no estilo sistema de noticias.

Porém na página que deve abrir o contéudo digitado e que deveria funcionar os plugins, ela exibi os textos com a formatação HTML perfeito, porém as partes css/js dos plugins não funciona, no caso as TABLES e SPOILER, elas não funcionam

EXEMPLO:

Permissions



    2
    
        
            Função| Function
            Permissão|Permission

COMO DEVERIA FICAR: (Print abaixo é do editor CKEditor, e deveria ficar desse jeito só que no site onde exibo as informações)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

COMO ESTÁ FICANDO: (Esta é a página para exibir as informações, deveria ficar como na print acima, porém, ela não está ficando com o formato correto)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]